# Literature on semiconductor modeling

Tags: resource-recommendations, simulations, semiconductor-physics

[*Analysis and Simulation of Semiconductor Devices* by Selberherr](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3709187540) (Amazon link) seems to be the book on the basics of the craft, yet it was written in 1984. Are there any more recent books or have the fundamentals not changed since?

Comment: What kind of modeling are you interested in? More towards materials, physicxor devices?

Comment: According to my understanding there's the modelling necessary for the simulaton of processes, i.e. fabrication, and there's the one necessary for optical and electrical simulation. I am more interested in electrical simulation, e.g. IV or EQE measurements of a solar cell under illumination.